# How do you calculate distance between two cylindrical coordinates?

Tags: geometry, physics, cylindrical-coordinates

I can't figure out how to find the distance between these two points, expressed with cylindrical coordinates:
$P1 = (9.5 m, 1.00531 rad, 18.2 m)$
$P2 = (9.75 m, 5.27788 rad, 18.2 m)$

What is the precise method to find the distance between these two points? What is the formula?
Thanks.

Comment: This help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2410899/distance-in-modified-cylindrical-coordinates

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the law of cosines for the $r,\phi$ plane, then combine that with the $z$ difference (which you don't have here).
$$d^2=r_1^2+r_2^2-2r_1r_2 \cos(\phi_1-\phi_2) + (z_1-z_2)^2$$

Answer (score 2):

The two points have cartesian coordinates $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$ given by
$$x_i=r_i\cos\phi_i,\quad y_i=r_i\sin\phi_i, \quad z_i=z_i\ .$$
Their distance then is
$$d=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2+(z_1-z_2)^2}\ .$$